# How to add button to xib file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, xib

I got a view that I create from xib file, I have no problem when adding a UITableView. And then I tried to add a button to the xib file. The button is not appear on my screen. I already connect the button using IBOutlet to the header file.

> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *deleteNotificationButton;

and my code in m file

```
[self.view addSubview:_tblMain];
[self.view addSubview:_deleteNotificationButton
```

this is my storyboard screenshot
[image]

the debug hierarchy
[image]

the table appear but not the button, How can I make the button appear?

Comment: You can't put an `UIButton` as subview of an `UITableView` from xib file. Tableviews have their own subviews (header, footer and cells) if you need to put a button, you must add it as a subview of one of them.

Comment: self.view is not uitableview

Comment: Why are you adding the views as subviews in your implementation file? By placing them in your xib, they're already in the view hierarchy.

Comment: @Stonz2 I tried both way with just using iboutlet and adding view as subview neither working for me

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about the hierarchy. You need not write any code, only do this in Storyboard or xib file.

This is the hierarchy about the view, you should use the UIView as the root view not UITableView.
[image]
[image]

Then run the project, well. By the way, if you set UIView as rootView, self.view = the UIView you did set, if you set UITableView as rootView, self.view = UITableView.
[image]

You can debug with this button, when the project is running, this button will be shown, then check whether the button in the view.
[image]

Comment: I didn't find my button, I even didn't find my table too

Answer (score 0):

```
 #Just use this line I have added below your two lines.Hope this works.


 [self.view addSubview:_tblMain];
 [self.view addSubview:_deleteNotificationButton
 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_deleteNotificationButton];
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the button still not appear

Comment: `addSubview:` always add the view on top, there for the third line of code is irrelevant.